# Springboot autowired null value

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm fairly new to Spring & Spring boot, trying to wrap my head around with the concepts.
I have this sample class, this is just a typed up code to show what i'm trying to do. There are no compilation errors. When I start the server, the MQConnection class code gets executed, the mq properties from the appplication.properties are read and printing. But when another class tries to call the send message to MQ, i'm seeing NUllPointerException

```
@Component
public class MQConnection {

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String host;

    private Connection connection;

    @Autowired
    public MQConnection(@value("${username}") String username, 
            @value("${password}") String password, @value("${host}") String host) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.host = host;
        init();
    }

    public getConnection() {
        return connection 
    }

    private init() {
        connection = mqconnection;
        System.out.println(username, password, host); // I see the value when the server is started
        //code to connect to mq

    }

}
```

What am I missing, these autowired & beans is really confusing for me as i'm new to Spring world. Am I using right flow or completely absurd, I don't know

```
@Component
public class MQSendMessage {

    @Autowired
    MQConnection mqConnection;

    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        connection = mqConnection.getConnection(); //NULL value
        //send messageCode throws nullpointerexception
    }
}

public class AnotherClass {

    @Autowired
    MQSendMessage messageq;

    public doSomething() {

        messageq.sendMessage("hello world"); 
    }
}
```

Any help to fix the connection that throws nullpointer

Comment: Show the actual stack trace and the code where it starts.

Comment: As you haven't posted the full code looking at your `init` method looks like you are assigning `mqconnection` to `connection` to early before it actually is available.

Comment: pls show us your stacktrace

Comment: @dit The stacktrace is from MQ connection, because the connection is null. The AnotherClass class is sending message to MQ where the connection is null

Comment: @M.Deinum What can i modify to fix the issue, i need it badly to get fixed

Comment: Like @M.Deinum said, your are calling `MQSendMessage#sendMessage` before the spring bean initialization complete.

Comment: @dit Yes, i think that might be mistake on my part for not knowing much about spring. How can i update the code to make it work ?

Comment: @M.Deinum I added `@PostConstruct public getConnection() {
        return connection 
    }` , but still no luck

Comment: That won't make any difference... The problem is your init code. Also why are you directly using a `MqConnection`? Isn't it possible to use JMS or are you using plain MQ?

Comment: @M.Deinum its a `JMS connection` in the `init ()` method.

Comment: Then why not use the default JMS support in Spring Boot? Also don't use a `@Component` it is configuration so use it as such.

Comment: @M.Deinum   Sorry, my bad. I copied existing code from another proj in my organization. Its not JMS, using `MQQueueConnectionFactory` & `MQQueueConnection`

Comment: Which implements the JMS api. Nonetheless you are trying to configure stuff in a component whereas it should be configuration not a component.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152580/discussion-between-user525146-and-m-deinum).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `AnotherClass` is not instantiated by Spring container. If you want to use Spring-annotation like convention then you have to annotate your class with e.g.`@Component` annotation. Otherwise Spring wont instantiate this object for you.

#### Useful tip

Try using constructor injection instead of a field injection. Just like in your `MQConnection` class. You can even mark all your class fields instantiated in the construct with `final` keyword so you will be sure that these values wont change (if they are immutable of course) during bean life cycle. Then `AnotherClass` could look like this:

```
public class AnotherClass {

    private final MQSendMessage messageq;

    @Autowired
    public AnotherClass(MQSendMessage messageq) {
        this.messageq = messageq
    }

    public doSomething() {
        messageq.sendMessage("hello world");
    }
}
```

#### Spring Boot documentation

Also please read carefully Spring Boot documentation on [Spring Beans and dependency injection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html). It is very well written and describes basic concepts in details. It will make your learning much easier and faster.

I hope it helps.

Comment: It didn't work, AnotherClass is called by the controller to do some parsing & send the message to MQ channel

Comment: @user525146 How do inject `AnotherClass` to component? Do you use injection like `@Autowired AnotherClass anotherClass` or do you do `new AnotherClass()`? If you create this object by hand you have to provide `MQSendMessage` because when you create objects with `new` construct then there is no injection from Spring side.

Comment: no, I'm not creating object. i have a static method in that class, that i'm calling directly from the controller

Comment: @user525146 Can you show this method in your question? If you refer to spring bean from static method then you have `NullPointerException` guaranteed - spring does not inject anything in static context. Show us exactly where this NPE happens so we can help you in finding right solution to your problem.

Comment: I see stack trace for NullPointerException from MQ because the connection value is null